Difference between folder created using API and folder created using drag & drop on google cloud storage
Trying to fetch metadata for object created using drag and drop on GCS
I am encountering an issue where when i created a folder on gcs using API and tried to fetch its metadata using
      const metaData = await bucketInstance.file(file).getMetadata();

It returned me all the appropriate metadata, but when i tried to fetch metadata for a folder which contained some files and which i uploaded using drag and drop it is saying object doesn't exists;

No such object: bucket_name/path1/path2/Cloud-Register/path3/Test 1/


Folders don't actually exist in Cloud Storage.  As such, they have no metadata, and the error message you received makes total sense.  If you want to store some extra data about some group or collection of objects in Cloud Storage, object metadata is not going to work very well.  Perhaps you should duplicate that metadata to each of the objects in the simulated folder, or use another data store (such as a database).  But you won't able to read or write any metadata to a simulated folder.

It's not perfectly accurate. Managed folders have been released recently https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managed-folders But your answer is right: you can't set metadata in that managed folder. Duplication on object is better
